# Cassandra setFetchSize and number of rows returned

Tags: scala, cassandra

I wrote the following program to query rows from a table called Foo in cassandra. The table has 431 rows.

```
val session = getDevTestSession()
val stmt = session.prepare("select * from foo where token(id) > ? and token(id) <= ?")
val ps = stmt.bind(new Long(Long.MIN_VALUE), new Long(Long.MAX_VALUE))
   .setFetchSize(1000)
   .setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ONE)
val resultSet = session.execute(ps)
val iterator = resultSet.iterator()
var rowCount = 0
var expireCount = 0
while(!resultSet.isFullyFetched) {
   resultSet.fetchMoreResults()
   val row = iterator.next()
   if (row != null) {
      rowCount += 1
   }
}
println(s"total number of rows ${rowCount}")
session.close()
```

This program returned 0 number of rows.

I changed the program and set

```
.setFetchSize(1)
```

Now the program returned all 431 rows.

I changed the program to

```
.setFetchSize(100)
```

Now the program returned just 400 rows.

What I want is that if the fetch size is 100, but the number of remaining rows is just 31, then the program should return the 31 rows and not return empty results. It seems that if the number of rows is less than the fetchSize then it comes back empty rather than returning whatever is available.

My cassandra driver is

```
"com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "3.1.4"
```

Comment: The code shown does not utilize JDBC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!isFullyFetched() never guarantees that the result set is not exhausted (you should call isExhausted() to verify it).

isExhausted()

> Returns whether this ResultSet has more results.

Source : https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html

Answer (score 0):

Number of rows can be counted by the following way :

```
  val cql = "select id from tableStudent"

  val resultSet = cassandraSession.execute(cql)

  val rowCount = resultSet.getAvailableWithoutFetching
```

"getAvailableWithoutFetching will give the number of rows returned by cql execution"

Comment: getAvailableWithoutFetching()
The number of rows that can be retrieved from this result set without blocking to fetch.

Comment: getAvailableWithoutFetching() will give you the number of rows fetched into the memory, not the total number of rows.